# wordpress feed not working,.!

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I have a wordpress website,. but when i go to /feed its gives me this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><feed
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"
  xml:lang="en-US"
  xml:base="http://www.ladakhimusic.com/wp-atom.php"
 >
<title type="text">Ladakhi Music &#187; Page not found</title>
<subtitle type="text">One Stop For All Ladakhi Music Lovers,.!!</subtitle>

<updated>2014-09-16T20:52:09Z</updated>

<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.ladakhimusic.com" />
<id>http://www.ladakhimusic.com/feed/atom/</id>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.ladakhimusic.com/atom" />

<generator uri="http://wordpress.org/" version="3.9.2">WordPress</generator>
```

please help.,.!

Comment: Is that the entire file that you pasted, or just a part of it?

Comment: Thnx for replying., yes it's the entire thing I am getting on the page.,!!

Comment: I've seen something like this happen with an errant character that was accidentally typed into one of the theme files.  Try switching to the default theme and see if that fixes it.  Also view the source of that /feed page in your browser and see if that is also cutoff.  If an xml file is invalid, sometimes browsers like chrome only display part of it, but if you view the source you can see all of it.  That might give you an indication of where the code is breaking.

Comment: the source is also same

Comment: i tried after switching to theme twenty fourteen,.. but no use,.!!

Comment: ok, so if you've disabled all plugins, and switched to the default theme, there are only a couple of options left.  One, there might be some strange character in one of your posts that's making this break.  Or two, there is something wrong with your wordpress installation.  So try moving all of your posts to the trash (you can recover them later), and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it is a plugin.  I downloaded the theme you're using and didn't see anything in the code that lead me to believe that there was something in it that was causing the trouble.  I would disable each plugin one by one and see if the feed comes back.

Comment: I have tried deactivating the plugins but of no use.,, I use yoast SEO plugin., does it interfere with rss.,?? I tried after deactivating it bt no help.,,